# Powering the USB ports on and off using cron on the Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, bash, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi3, libusb

Thanks for looking at this post.  I have set up a Raspberry Pi 3 B plus as a remote time lapse camera that is powered by a solar panel.  The Pi shuts down at night to save power and the Wakeup alarm on the Pijuice board turns it on in the morning.  I would like to turn the USB ports on and off once an hour so the Huawei USB dongle sim card can communicate over the mobile cellular network to upload the photos to my Google Drive account.  The reason for wanting the USB ports to be off most of the time is to save battery power, especially on cloudy days.
I know that the following commands will turn off and on the USB ports;

Turn OFF USB chip
`echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`

Turn ON USB chip
`echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind`

What I would like to do is have these in a script that can be scheduled as a crontab.  I tried the following but it did not work. The file was called usb-on.sh

```
#! /bin/sh 
#this is a script that I made up for turning on the USB ports
echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`
```

When I tested the script I got the following error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo sh usb-on.sh
1-1
tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind: No such device
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: You will need to poke through your USB tree to figure out which port number you need.  And note that you don't have to use `sudo` to run the script as long as the script is using `sudo` to touch the file.  Looking through `dmesg` might show you which device is the dongle.

Comment: On most platforms it won’t give you a desired effect. What you rather need is run time power management to be implemented. And I believe with newest kernels it’s more or less true.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out by just adding the command to a crontab.

CRONTAB to turn on and off the USB ports
Open terminal

`crontab -e`

add the following

`#Turn on USB ports at the top of the hour
0 * * * * echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind

#Turn off USB ports 5 minutes after the hour
5 * * * * echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`